while using python selenium --headless=new and user-data-dir together, it always pop up a white window
I have following scipt:
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    chrome_driver_path = r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"  # Update this path
    # Set up ChromeDriver service
    service = Service(chrome_driver_path)

    # Set up Chrome options to use the existing profile
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")  
    chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=c:\Users\...\Default")  # Path to your Chrome profile


    # Initialize Selenium WebDriver with the same profile
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)


The script will use the profile defined in user-data-dir and execute in headless mode, it works well except it will pop up a white window, how to hide that?

The entire screen except the Windows taskbar will go white. To clear the white screen I need to alt-tab twice.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I started having this exact same problem a few days ago. Seems to be due to a buggy Chrome update, as I didn't modify my code at all and I know Chrome automatically updates itself sometimes. --headless=old doesn't have this problem but my script doesn't work with --headless=old so I don't have a workaround at the moment.

Maybe try to use old version --headless  instead of --headless=new. Or you can also try to use chrome_options.add_argument("--no-startup-window").

@lukos06 --headless seems to be an alias for --headless=new now, and --headless=old doesn't work as I explained previously. --no-startup-window does avoid the white screen, but my script crashed with "selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from unknown error: unable to discover open pages".

This problem seems to have been fixed now in Chrome/ChromeDriver version 130 (or possibly earlier).
